# helm: no endpoints available for service "external-secrets-webhook"

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

When running:

`helm upgrade --install backend ./k8s "$@"`

Gives me the next error (did not happen before):

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "api" with kind ExternalSecret: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.externalsecret.external-secrets.io": Post "https://external-secrets-webhook.external-secrets.svc:443/validate-external-secrets-io-v1beta1-externalsecret?timeout=5s": no endpoints available for service "external-secrets-webhook"

Any idea on how what is it or how to debug, --atomic also doesn't roll back for the same reason.

The helm config is:

```
{{- if .Values.awsSecret.enabled }}
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    {{- include "application.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  refreshInterval: 1m
  secretStoreRef:
    name: cluster-secret-store
    kind: ClusterSecretStore
  target:
    name: {{ .Values.applicationName }}
    creationPolicy: Owner
  dataFrom:
  - extract:
      key: {{ .Values.awsSecret.name }}
{{- end }}
```

and the gihutbActions

```
            - helm/upgrade-helm-chart:
                atomic: false
                chart: ./k8s
                helm-version: v3.8.2
                release-name: backend
                namespace: default
                values: ./k8s/values-${ENV}.yaml
                values-to-override:
                    "image.tag=${CIRCLE_TAG},\
                    image.repository=trak-${ENV}-backend,\
                    image.registry=${AWS_ECR_ACCOUNT},\
                    env=${ENV},\
                    applicationName=api,\
                    applicationVersion=${CIRCLE_TAG}"
```

Thank you

I have tried setting --atomic to true but doesn't rollBack, this morning we did a few changes on roles and permissions but should not affect this at all.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error while running helm upgrades as well. Given that the error complains specifically about `no endpoints available for service "external-secrets-webhook"`, I looked for issues with the service within the Kubernetes cluster. The immediate fix was to delete pods in the Kubernetes cluster that weren't in a `READY` state.

```
$ kubectl get all -n external-secrets 
NAME                                                    READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pod/external-secrets-7fb7c86ccd-2dw85                   1/1     Running             0          2d22h
pod/external-secrets-cert-controller-767cbdcddf-9ljmm   0/1     Running             0          2d22h
pod/external-secrets-webhook-dcd4f4758-zg8sp            0/1     ContainerCreating   0          2d22h
```

Running `$ kubectl delete pod` on the `cert-controller` and `webhook` pods resolved the issue.